# Correct phrasing for describing a plot

Tags: mathematics

I am describing a plot (in a figure in a thesis I am currently writing) as follows:

*Figure of [names of some mathematical functions]. **Function A** is covered by **Function B** for x < 10. (...)*

Is this correct?

Basically I want to describe that **Function B** has the same values for x < 10 compared to **Function A**. That is why **Function B** is only plotted for x >= 10.

Comment: Let f,g be the functions such that f,g < 10 but g >= 10, is that what you want?  - It seems like a piecewise function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest that you use the verbs **coincide** and **overlap**. Consider:

[image]

> As you can see, output (result) of the function A **coincide (overlap)** perfectly with the result of function B for input variables lower than 10.

---

You can also say:

> The Figure illustrates the excellent **agreement** between the result of the function A and function B for input variables lower than 10.

Comment: Would you not prefer the term *image [of a function f]* to *output (result) of the function f*; and *input values*, or simply *inputs* to *input variables*? Also, I would dispense with *excellent* in the second sentence. “Note: *g*'s image coincides with *f*'s for inputs less than 10.”

Comment: @user2684291 "image of a function" sounds awkward to me as well as using apostrophe with functions.

Comment: I've seen these terms quite often—I'm not sure why they'd sound awkward. I suppose, perhaps in scientific papers, they're not that commonly used or summat? You can google `image of a function`, and if *f* is a name of a function then “*f*'s” corresponds to “of *f*”.